# react native - react-native-maps performance slow on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-native

this is the first time I have integrated the Google Map on iOS using `react-native-maps`. I am able to show the Google Map on iOS by following step by step in this link:

[react-native-maps with Google Map on iOS](https://medium.com/@kswanie21/react-native-google-map-with-react-native-maps-572e3d3eee14)

Then, the new problem appear that the performance of the map is terrible (I cannot move a map).

## UPDATE

Here is my code:

The region will be saved in state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        region: {
            latitude: 10.762622,
            longitude: 106.660172,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0100,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0100,
        },
    }
}
```

Here is the code to show the map:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View
                style={styles.mapContainer}>
                <MapView
                    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                    style={styles.map}
                    region={this.state.region}
                    showsUserLocation={true}
                    onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete.bind(this)}
                >
                </MapView>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

onRegionChangeComplete(region) {
    console.log("region", region);
    this.setState({region: region});
}
```

These code work fine on Android, but I am not able to move the map on iOS

Please let me know if you have any ideas to solve this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post your code. Also, keep in mind emulators are slower. Also, you cannot drag at all or it is just very slow? Because if you want to drag the map you might need to enable it.

Comment: @sfratini: I updated my question. Please let me know if you need any information.

Comment: Thanks. I added my answer. Nothing really wrong with the code but something you could try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, there are a couple of things I don't like about the code that I think could be bothering you:

1. Using the Google Provider in iOS: Is it installed? Working correctly? I usually use the default iOS map because I am guessing is more optimized.
2. You are using console.log() in the onRegionChange which could be executed a lot of times. I had some iOS performance issues in Debug because I was using a lot of console.log() in the render method which was slowing the emulator.
3. It seems the region is pointing to a region in the state and you are updating the region again when is moving.

So, I would try this:

- Remove the console.log or make sure is not logging a lot inside
  XCode.
- Replace region for initialRegion in the map. No need to keep
  updating it.  Just save it in another variable if you want.
- Remove the provider prop to see if the regular iOS
  MapKit works.

Also, keep in mind MapView has some props to actually disable the scrolling but I assume you already tried that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. "Replace region for initialRegion in the map. No need to keep updating it. Just save it in another variable if you want." This work for me.